# Matrix handler large sequences

Tags: c++, matrix

I m going to do an algorithm like needleman-wunsch algorithm or smith-watterman algorithm for large sequences. So I'm going to need a way to create matrices of different sizes so my question is which library gives me the best performance on that and would be easy to use.

P.S: I know that OpenCV, and Boost can handle the matrices but I don't know if there are good to do operations on it.

Comment: You could do simply with `std::vector< std::vector<float> >` but if you want to use libary just pick one and go with it, no need to waste time on which is the best. Just make sure your code is general enough so you can simply swap out the library and use a different one, that way you can test between different library at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If “the best performance” is the requirement, then you have to look at NVIDIA CUDA or Intel MKL. Libraries like C++ boost uBLAS concentrate not on performance, but on usability.